General number of classical bits: recycles qubits
I am trying to write a Qiskit routine to perform qubit recycling for Shor's algorithm. This is a procedure by which the M-bit control register is replaced by a single quantum register, and the measurements of this register are fed forward to choose the phase gates for the QFT. The circuit is as follows for M=5 control qubits: 
n_control = 1    
n_work = L

# Quantum circuit
m = QuantumRegister(n_control, name='m')
w = QuantumRegister(n_work, name='w')
    
# classical registers
cl_reg = list(range(M))
for c in range(M):
    cl_name = 'cl' + str(c)
    cl_reg[c] = ClassicalRegister(1, name=cl_name)
# hard-wired for M=5 # <==x I need to generalize this line
qc = QuantumCircuit(m, w, cl_reg[0], cl_reg[1], cl_reg[2], cl_reg[3], cl_reg[4]) 
    

# Work register in state |1>
qc.x(1)

# increment counter    
for cnt in range(M):
            
    # initialize control register to 0
    qc.initialize([1, 0], m)

    # Apply H to control register
    qc.h(0)
        
    # apply ME operator
    power = 2**(M-cnt-1)    
    qc.append(c_U1(N, a, n_work, power, u_ver, trnc_lv, barrier=False), 
                  [0] + [i+n_control for i in range(n_work)])

    # decorate control register using feed-forward phase operators
    qc.h(0)
    for myn in range(cnt):
        qc.p(np.pi/2**(cnt-myn), 0).c_if(cl_reg[myn], 1)

    # measure control register
    qc.measure(m, cl_reg[cnt])
    qc.barrier()

# draw circuit
qc.draw(fold=50)
plt.show()

Unfortunately, the code
qc = QuantumCircuit(m, w, [cl_reg[i] for i in range(M)]) 
gives an error, as I can't use a list in QuantumCircuit. How can I attach a general number M of classical registers without hard-wiring the value of M as in the code above? Also, I need separate classical registers for each bit of M, so I can't collapse the classical register to a single register. And I need to cut on previous registers, so I need to remember results of past measurements.

Maybe a better way of asking the question is as  follows. I have a qiskit code that  implements the recycled qubit circuit originally posted. My code works for general values of M, except for the quantum circuit initialization. I have hardwired this to M=5 in the example code and the figure. Can someone help me with quantum circuit initialization for a general M?

You can use the unpacking operator:
qc = QuantumCircuit(m, w, *[cl_reg[i] for i in range(M)])

